# Net.WebClient.DownloadFile to download file of Google Drive from batch file not recognize some characters

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying download a file that is hosted on Google Drive via batch file and using `Net.WebClient.DownloadFile` function but this not is able to recognize some characters present on url.

This is the error received on console:

[image]

Here is my last attempt:

```
    @echo off

    SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

    set downloadurl="https://drive.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=1gCLfIwL2FfswelXIsK6tkWm5kCRSTNh8&export=download"
    set downloadpath=%LOCALAPPDATA%\test.txt

    powershell -command "& { (New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('%downloadurl%', '%downloadpath%'); }"

    pause
```

How i can solve it?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotes in your SET statement are being interpreted by cmd so then it tries to keep interpreting and gets confused by the single quotes.  Change your code as such:

```
@ECHO OFF

SET "downloadurl=https://drive.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=1gCLfIwL2FfswelXIsK6tkWm5kCRSTNh8&export=download"

powershell.exe -Command "Invoke-WebRequest -Uri %downloadurl% -OutFile $Env:LocalAppData\test.txt"

PAUSE
```